# Trying to add hotel names from booking.com in an python array while clicking on next page automaticly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

mylist=[]
my_category=""

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python27\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('http://booking.com')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ss").send_keys("Rhodes, Greece")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sb-searchbox__button").submit()

category = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.sr-hotel__name")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, '.paging-next')))
    try:
        for link in category:
            my_category = link.text
            print (my_category)
            mylist.append(my_category)
            element=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next page')))
            element.click()
    except TimeoutException:
            break
```

And here is the ERROR message I got:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/ΧΡΗΣΤΟΣ/PycharmProjects/HotelScrap/HotelScrapPackage/HotelScrapPythonFileIndex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/�������/PycharmProjects/HotelScrap/HotelScrapPackage/HotelScrapPythonFileIndex.py", line 28, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, '.paging-next')))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: And your question is.... (drums)

Comment: Good morning @WillemVanOnsem. Actually.... I can't do it! I can't figure out the way to add hotel names into an array and keep on clicking on Next Page in my above code.... Any help will be lifesaving!

Comment: @ChristosGalousis, you should specify the **reason** why you *can't do it* and exception log if you have any... and the question also:)

Comment: Hello @Andersson and thank you for your time and comments. I have added the error message after I run my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish the usage of class name in search by `CLASS_NAME` and by `CSS_SELECTOR`:

Suppose we have `<a class="paging-next">`

- if you use `By.CLASS_NAME` to locate element, you should use it as

  `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'paging-next')))`

Note, that there **is no dot** before class name (`'paging-next'`)

- if you use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` to locate element, you should use it as

  `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.paging-next')))`

Note, that there **is a dot** before class name (`'.paging-next'`)

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer to my problem. I will re-post it with a most appropriate way because I still can not solve the issue to click on the Next page and add those hotel names into an array...